# How to pull data from a php array if a certain value from the same array is given

Tags: php, arrays, xml, json

I want to extract a information from a PHP array based on a given information.

PHP code is

```
$xmlstring = file_get_contents('file.xml');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
$HotelCodes = array('BG01I9', 'BG53I4', 'BG23I7');
$code = $HotelCodes[1];
if (!$code) {
   throw new Exception("No Hotel Code specified");
}
foreach ($HotelCodes as $code) {
  foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
    if (strcasecmp($hotel['HotelCode'], $code) === 0) {
        echo "{$hotel['Latitude']}:{$hotel['Longitude']}<br/>";
        foreach ($hotel['HotelImages']['ImageUrl'] as $img) {
            echo "<img src='{$img}'/><hr/>";
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

`print_r $array`with one record is (the array has multiple records):

```
Array
( 
    [Hotel] => Array 
  ( 
[0] => Array ( 
     [HotelCode] => BG01I9 
     [Latitude] => 42.6039 
     [Longitude] => 23.3954 
     [HotelImages] => Array ( 
           [ImageURL] => Array ( 
                        [0] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481077_0x0.jpg 
                        [1] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481092_0x0.jpg 
                        [2] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481109_0x0.jpg 
                        [3] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481139_0x0.jpg 
                        [4] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481163_0x0.jpg 
                        [5] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6480990_0x0.jpg 
                        [6] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481002_0x0.jpg 
                        [7] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481015_0x0.jpg 
                        [8] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481033_0x0.jpg 
                        [9] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/BG01I9/6481058_0x0.jpg 
   ) 
  ) 
 ) 
)
```

And i want to echo the Hotel Images, Latitude and Longitude based on the HotelCodes given by me:
The hotel code is `$HotelCodes[0]`

The error received is :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No Hotel Code specified' in /home/truckass/public_html/site/test/teste.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/truckass/public_html/siteo/test/teste.php on line 10
```

I need to echo for `HotelCodes[1]`

```
$img[1][0] ....$img[1][5] 
$Latitude[1]
$Longitude[1]
```

Could you please assist.

Answer (score 1):

This is the mistake:

```
$HotelCodes[] = array('BG01I9', 'BG53I4', 'BG23I7');
```

You should omit the first brackets:

```
$HotelCodes = array('BG01I9', 'BG53I4', 'BG23I7');
```

You can now access the second code by using `$HotelCodes[1]`.

In your snippet, you created an array with an array. That in itself is perfectly valid, but then you should access the value by using `$HotelCodes[0][1]`.

If you wanna stick with the square brackets, you can do this (>= 5.4):

```
$HotelCodes = ['BG01I9', 'BG53I4', 'BG23I7'];
```

Comment: Now i get 'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ' from line 'foreach ($hotels as $hotel) { '

Comment: I don't see $hotels defined anywhere.